# Running echo command without ending ";"

Tags: php

I am freaking out because I have always known that every line in PHP should end with "`;`". My question is simple: Is it possible to run the command `echo` without ending the line with "`;`"?

I am sorry if this is a dumb question but I am running this code with multiple `echo` commands without ending them and everything works just perfectly fine! I just don't understand how is this possible or should it be?

```
 <input name="of_instores[]" id="check<?php echo $row['st_id'] ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['st_id'] ?>">
 <label for="check<?php echo $row['st_id'] ?>"><strong><?php echo $row['st_title'] ?></strong> | <?php echo $row['st_city'] ?></label>
```

Comment: This is covered in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Answer (score 0):

When this:

```
<?php echo "Hello" ?>
```

is executed, the script **ends** at the `?>` or simply *implies* a **semi-colon**. So you don't need to put a semi-colon for that.

Answer (score 0):

The last command used before the `?>` can be written without a semicolon (;).

This does not mean you should now create files full of starting and ending php context just to not have to use semicolons ;)